# Error using yarn install / can't answer a question unless a user TTY

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, yarnpkg

I'm using `yarn` on **Debian Stretch (4.9.168)**, having a Jenkins installed and trying to run `yarn install --no-progress --flat --network-timeout=1000000` out of my Jenkinsfile.

`yarn` has been installed via Global Configuration for Node.JS on Jenkins (`npm install -g yarn@latest`), but as soon as the Jenkinsfile tries to run the above mentions install command, I get the following error:

```
+ yarn install --no-progress --flat --network-timeout=1000000
yarn install v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Can't answer a question unless a user TTY".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/data/jenkins/workspace/REPONAME_PR-1-head/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
script returned exit code 1
```

So apparently yarn has been installed correctly. A bit of search brought some information for Windows, but not how to fix it for Linux. Does anyone have any clue how to fix this problem?

Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'linux'
  }

  tools {
    nodejs "NodeJS_v11.9.0"
  }

  stages {
    stage("Cleanup") {
      steps {
        sh yarn cache clean
        dir('node_modules') {
          deleteDir()
        }
      }
    }
    stage("Install dependencies") {
      failFast true
      steps {
        sh yarn install --no-progress --flat --network-timeout=1000000
      }
    }

  }

}
```